# sending javascript variable to php script via post without form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know there are quite a few questions like mine, but I'm attempting to pass a javascript variable to a php script using AJAX. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Can't seem to figure it out. My javascript on original page:

```
var myvariable = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
// send variable to server via ajax here  
$.ajax({
   url: 'myphp.php',
   data: { myvariable : myvariable },
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(result) {
    alert("success!");
       }
});
```

and then to receive on the 'myphp.php' page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['myvariable']))
{
$myvariable = $_POST['myvariable'];
}
?>
```

I'm trying to do this without using a form submit - I just want it to send the variable via ajax on page load. Attempting to echo or print the variable $myvariable results in a blank page. Also trying to use this variable in an API call gives me a warning that the field is blank.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Are you sure myvariable is not null?

Comment: var myvariable = document.documentElement.innerHTML; ?

Comment: success : function () is deprecated use .done (function() instead. also its document.getElementByID () or ByName (), etc

Comment: check developer console you should have error...

Comment: Your data should be sent as a post... I think @samitha might be on to something...

Comment: @LaytonEverson OP didn't reply to us

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you want to do but unfortunately its logic is misplaced.

PHP loads before Javascript since the server parses it before sending to your browser.  So `$myvariable` has no value until it receives it from the AJAX request, which doesn't come until after the page has actually loaded.  Since the new version of the page isn't being re-requested, you don't see anything new appear.

You need a way to communicate the variable from the PHP file back to the browser dynamically.  This is done using JSON or something similar to send variables back to Javascript directly for parsing in the browser.

Once you have the JSON library on your server, you'll set the `dataType: json` in your Javascript and in your PHP you call `json_encode($responseData);`.

Oh yeah and like the others said:

```
var myvariable = document.getElementByID('idforelement');
```

Comment: Well that's my answer...No matter how I change the javascript, the php is always loading first and viewing my variable as empty. Not the answer I was hoping for, but the proper answer, I think.

Comment: so if I do $myvariable = json_encode($responseData); on on the php page and then proceed to use $myvariable in php it's null. Sorry for dumb questions and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Read this to make ajax call : [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

And use `document.getElementByID('element_id').innerHTML` OR `document.getElementByName(' ').innerHTML` to get element's innerHTML value.